# Is there an implementation of IList<T> where Contains(T) is an O(1) operation?

Tags: c#, collections

I'm wondering if there is an `IList<T>` implementation that's backed by a hash like `HashSet<T>` but offers indexed access?

To be clear, I'm not concerned on how to implement one, just wondering if anyone knows if it's already available.

Comment: Just so everyone's aware of what I mean, an `IList<T>` provides indexed accessors `myList[0]` returns the first element, so any implementation needs to inherit from `IList<T>`. I have my own implementation but things like `RemoveAt(int)` need careful attention to ensure that the backing list is updated and subsequently my implementation is O(n) but I don't really remove so that's okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement `IList<T>` yourself and keep two backing collections - a `List<T>` *and* a `HashSet<T>`. Basically get Visual Studio to provide a "throw exception" implementation for everything in `IList<T>`, then for each method work out whether you want to proxy it to the list or the set.

Of course you'd have to be careful for duplicates etc (define the behaviour of `Add(x)`, `Add(x)`, `Remove(x)`, `Contains(x)` - you could end up with it in the list but not the set) but it wouldn't be too hard.

Comment: That's how I'm doing it at the moment, I have an IList<T> implementation that has a hash based backing table to allow close-to O(1) Contains(T) and IndexOf(T) operations.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET 4 there is a new `SortedSet<T>` class where `Contains()` is O(1), see [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd382336(VS.100).aspx)

Comment: A `SortedSet<T>` is not an `IList<T>`

Comment: Brett, you're right, I assumed that but didn't check. I made an Edit so that people can take their upvote back.

Comment: That's cool, I imagine in 4.0 I'll be using the `SortedSet<T>` right away for other tasks. It's good to see some new data structures appearing.

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer - no, it is not already available.

Implementing it is of course easy as you realise. The reason why it is not commonly implemented is as follows. If you can do contains in O(1) then you could do index lookup in O(1). But of course index lookup is not unique if you have duplicate elements.

As what you essentially need is two data structures, a Set (or Map) and a List, and there isn't a much more efficient way of doing it than this, the standard library authors leave you to combine the data-structures yourself.

Comment: Thanks Nick, it could be argued that a `HashSet<T>` also requires two data structures, it would require a backing table also, yet it's a very useful structure, and as soon as I started using 3.5 I replaced my own implementation with it.

Comment: I'd argue a HashSet is a single data-structure, a table (though some use linked lists as well). But an implementation which tried to do everything would be too bloated for most people's use, and an implementation which only did contains quickly would lead to people moaning about indexOf etc.

Answer (score 0):

[`KeyedCollection<TKey, TItem>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438.aspx) provides this type of functionality, though you do have to derive from it and provide it with a function to extract a key from the item which is hashed.

Comment: This wouldn't serve as a hash backed `IList<T>` implementation as it requires the key to be unique and doesn't allow duplicate items.

Answer (score 0):

You can have any number of (hashed or other) indexes into doubly linked list nodes (doubly linked so you have O(1) deletion).

Answer (score 0):

There is none in .Net 3.5, but its very easy to implement one:

```
public class Set<T> : KeyedCollection<T,T>
{
    public Set()
    {}

    public Set(IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        foreach (T elem in collection)
        {
            Add(elem);
        }
    }

    protected override T GetKeyForItem(T item)
    {
        return item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[HashSet<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) implements `ICollection<T>`, if that's any use. Available from 3.5 onwards.

Comment: Yep, but again, it's not an `IList<T>`.

Comment: Sure, just didn't know if you could get away with ICollection instead of IList.